# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+1/2+...+1/n)\frac{\sin{nx}}{n}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, infinity

As mentioned in the title.

I’m trying to solve this problem by estimating $1+1/2+…+1/n$:$$1+\frac{1}{2}+…\frac{1}{n}=\ln(n)+\gamma+o(1)$$
Where $\gamma=0.57721...$ is **Euler–Mascheroni constant**. Then we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+\frac{1}{2}+…\frac{1}{n})\frac{\sin{nx}}{n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n\sin{nx}}{n}+ \gamma\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nx}}{n}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nx}}{n} o(1)$$

I have problem continuing because I do not know how to handle the first term and the third term of RHS.

P.s. I already know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{nx}}{n}$ is convergent due to **Dirichlet’s test**.

Comment: Related: [Title
Series $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n} \cdot \left(1+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}\right)$ convergence question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370402/series-sum-frac-sinnn-cdot-left1-cdots-frac1n-right-converg).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [For what values of $a$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1+\frac12 + \dotsb + \frac1n \right) \frac{\sin (na)}{n}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/625281/721644).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks @Invisible

Comment: I just think the method given in the first answer of your link looks too advanced for me, lol @ShubhrajitBhattacharya